# My Keyboard does not work in **Ubuntu terminal **whilst writing a source code

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, terminal

I have installed a **Virtual machine**.I use **Virtual Box** for the same.
My host OS is Windows XP SP3.
I have assigned it 500mb of Ram and it works fine.
But my problem is that my **Keyboard** does not work in **Ubuntu terminal** whilst writing a source code.

When I use the arrow keys it gives me alphabets **A B C D**.
And also when i press a **.** it acts as a backspace.
I have a **cordless Logitech Keyboard**.I don't know why my keyboard isn't functioning inside the **Terminal (& that to only whilst typing in source codes)**

I have tried changing the **Character Encoding** but thats not helping.

Please help.

**EDIT1** Somebody please help.

Comment: Might be worth explaining what application you are using to edit the specified source code.

Comment: What terminal are you using? What does `echo $TERM` print?

Comment: It sounds like the terminal software is detecting the virtual hardware of your VM incorrectly.  To fix it, you'll need to tell the terminal software which terminal type your virtual hardware most closely matches.  In my own (limited) experience, that may mean trying them one by one until you find one that works.  As for the steps to accomplish that, I'm hoping the more knowledgeable folks will chime in at this point.

Comment: @ Nifle -yea right I have the one with the echo $ print .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**vim editor** works fine.However in ***vi editor*** my keyboard still acts funny.

So for me **vim** s a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your keyboard is fine. The arrow keys shouldn't function inside vi (and it's sad that they're enabled by default in vim). Also, there are different modes in vim, maybe you tried to type while in command mode rather than insert mode?